# Cannot invoke method getLastSuccessfulBuild() on null object

Tags: jenkins, groovy, groovy-console

Unable to retrieve Jenkins job last successful job variables or Parameters via Groovy script so that I can pass these to next job as a variable.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
def job = Jenkins.instance.getJob("Testing-4")
def run = instance.getItems()
println run.getEnvironment()["PipelineId"]
```

Error logs

```
    ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getLastBuild() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:32)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:3)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:580)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:618)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:589)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:168)
    at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.run(SystemGroovy.java:95)
    at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.perform(SystemGroovy.java:59)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
```

Comment: After your edit, the given code and exception no longer make sense.

Comment: @doelleri Updated latest error logs

Answer (score 0):

From JavaDoc for `Jenkins.getItem()`:

> **Returns**: an item
>   whose `Item.getName()` is `name` and whose `Item.getParent()` is `this`, or
>   `null` if there is no such item, or there is but the current user lacks
>   both `Item.DISCOVER` and `Item.READ`.

For you, `getItem("Testing-4")` is returning `null`, so either there is no item with the name `"Testing-4"`, or you are not logged in as a user with the appropriate permissions.

You can get a list of items with `getItems()`, which would be useful in an exploratory script to find out what the items available to you look like.

Comment: import jenkins.model.Jenkins
def job = Jenkins.instance.getJob("Testing-4")
def run = job.getItems()

ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getItems() on null object
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:77)

Comment: `instance.getItems()` not `job.getItems()`. We've already established that `job` is null.

Comment: New ERROR: Build step failed with exception
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: instance for class: Script1
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)

Comment: I managed to get the code now. Could you help me in inserting groovy output to Jenkins Env variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
import hudson.model.*;

def lastSuccessfulPipelineID = build.getProject().getLastSuccessfulBuild().properties.get("envVars")['PipelineNumber']
def pa = new ParametersAction([
  new StringParameterValue("lastSuccessfulPipelineID", lastSuccessfulPipelineID)
])
println(lastSuccessfulPipelineID)

build.addAction(pa)
```

Comment: Could someone help me in inserting groovy output to Jenkins current job Env variable